# How to typehint a function which takes a callable and its args as parameters - e.g. a numerical integration of a function?

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-3.10

#### Problem

I have the following function (based on [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html?highlight=scipy%20integrate%20romb#scipy-integrate-quad)):

```
def simple_quad(func: Any, a: float, b: float, args: tuple = ()) -> float:
    def strips(n: int):
        for i in range(n):
            x = a + (b - a) * i / n
            yield func(x, *args) * 1 / n

    return sum(strips(1000))
```

... which basically evaluates `func` at a range of values and uses strips of fixed width to calculate the area under the graph. Optionally, parameters can be passed to `func` through the `args` tuple.

As you can see I've done some initial type-hints (in reality this is a .pyi stub for scipy), however I'm not happy with the typing of func & args being so loose. I want mypy to protect me from 2 things:

1. `func` is a callable which must have a first positional parameter which is a `float`, and return a `float`, and can have optional `*args`

   - i.e. `f(x:float, ...) -> float` at the very least
   - I guess it can also have **kwargs (although can't have [required name-only params](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/#:%7E:text=required%20keyword) or required positional params other than x)
2. The optional positional `*args` to `func` *must* match the contents of the splatted args tuple

---

#### Examples

```
def cubic(x: float, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float) -> float:
    "Function to evaluate a cubic polynomial with coefficients"
    return a + b * x + c * x ** 2 + d * x ** 3

simple_quad(cubic, a=1, b=10, args=(1, 2, 3, 4))  # fine, passes args to a,b,c,d and int is compatible with float signature
simple_quad(cubic, a=1, b=10)  # error from mypy as *args to `cubic` don't have default args so are all required
simple_quad(cubic, a=1, b=10, args=("a", "b", "c", "d"))  # arg length correct but type mismatch since cubic expects floats

x_squared: Callable[[float], float] = lambda x: x * x
simple_quad(x_squared, a=1, b=10, args=())  # should be fine as x_squared doesn't take any positional args other than x

def problematic(x: float, *, y: float) -> float: ...  # can't pass kwargs y via simple_quad, so can't be integrated
```

---

#### What I've tried

For `func` I tried to something with Protocol and Generics:

```
class OneDimensionalFunction(Protocol, Generic[T]): #double inheritance, although maybe I can get by with a metaclass for Generic
    def __call__(self, x: float, *args: T) -> float: ...
```

... in the hope I could write

```
def simple_quad(func: OneDimensionalFunction[T], a: float, b: float, args: tuple[T] = ()) -> float:

simple_quad(cubic, 1, 10, 10, (1,2,3,4)) # infer type requirement of args based on signature of func
# or
simple_quad[float,float,float,float](cubic, ...) #pass in additional type info above and beyond the expected Callable[[x:float,...], float]
```

... which has many problems I know, also Protocol doesn't play well with Callable if for example I want to pass in a lambda as func.

I labelled this python 3.10 as I think the new [Parameter Specification Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) may help, but I've only seen those used in decorators so I'm not sure how to apply them here. Let me know your thoughts

Comment: @OlvinRoght This is a tricky one I'm afraid

Comment: Logic like that does not belong in type-hints. It should be a runtime validation.

Comment: @rdas I don't know, it feels like a pretty easy way to shoot yourself in the foot, passing incompatible args to the function. It's only because of the additional redirection through a wrapper function that it becomes complicated to type, if func was a functools.partial it would be easier I think (but it can't be as scipy also accepts LowLevelCallables which need the args separate). Also I think [Parameter Specification Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) were added for at least this kind of problem; type-hinting *args of a callable parameter to a decorator.

Comment: Type hints don't prevent yourself from shooting yourself in the foot. In a strongly types language, the solution would be to define a type for `args` & use that instead. Trying to do something like that with type-hints - assuming it's possible - will be a ugly & unmaintainable IMO.

Comment: What makes you think it can have kwargs? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f2ef65dc7f00672496d7de6154744fee55ef95e9/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L49

Comment: @Reinderien Scipy can't pass any but it is valid for the callback to declare them, provided they are all optional. So the stub should technically allow callables with optional kwargs (so no `def foo(a, *, b )`)

Answer (score 1):

Use overloads with protocols. It's not great, but it gets you as close to real verification as you can probably get.

```
from typing import Protocol, Tuple, Any, overload, Union, Optional


class C1(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: float,                   ) -> float: ...
class C2(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: float, b: float,         ) -> float: ...
class C3(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: float, b: float, c: float) -> float: ...

ET = Tuple[()]
T1 = Tuple[float]
T2 = Tuple[float, float]
T3 = Tuple[float, float, float]

@overload
def quad(func: C1, a: float, b: float, args: Union[ET, T1] = ()) -> float: ...
@overload
def quad(func: C2, a: float, b: float, args: Union[ET, T2] = ()) -> float: ...
@overload
def quad(func: C3, a: float, b: float, args: Union[ET, T3] = ()) -> float: ...

def quad(func: Any, a: float, b: float, args: tuple = ()) -> float:
    return 0


def cubic(a: float, b: float, c: float, *, s: Optional[str] = None) -> float:
    return 0


quad(cubic, 0, 1)
```

Comment: This does give exactly the functionality I'm after, so fair enough. Would be nice to reduce the copy-paste of course - just wondering if you've had a chance to look into 3.10's [_Parameter Specification Variables_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) as they seem to be sort of related to this problem but I can't quite get my head around them...